# "Do you ever stop talking?" Is this structure "Do you ever+....." considered rude or sarcastic?

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language

**"Do you ever stop talking?"**

Is this sentence a bit sarcastic/rude or is it a neutral request that someone be quiet?

Comment: Implying that somebody talks too much is definitely rude, no matter how it's phrased, at least it is in English. I'd be surprised to hear there's any language where that's not rude, but I stand to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **rhetorical** to ask "Do you ever+....."
The expected answer is "NO" in general.

It may be **sarcastic or rude** (or a type of envy or criticism or insult) in some contexts , while it may be **praising or complimentary** or affectionate (or a type of laudation or flattery)  in some other contexts.

**Negative Sense :**
Much harassed school teachers may ask the school kids "Do you ever stop talking?" [[ rude ]]
Lonely parents may ask the grown up kids "Do you ever visit us?" [[ sarcastic ]]
Citizens may the local politicians "Do you ever work think about the environment?" [[ criticism or insult ]]

**Positive Sense :**
Dr Watson may ask Sherlock Holmes "Do you ever give up on a case?" [[ praise or complimentary ]]
A child may asking the caring overburdened parent "Do you ever think about yourself?" [[ affectionate ]]
A lawyer may ask a judge "Do you ever make wrong evaluations about the civil law?" [[ flattery ]]

Comment: A clarification: "Do you ever..." *can* be rhetorical, but it isn't always.  For example, "Do you ever visit the beach?" could be a perfectly neutral question.

Comment: Yes , that is Possible , here I was restricting to OP Example & Extrapolating a little on the wider Cases , but not covering all Cases , @stangdon , though I think , "Did you ever visit" seems like a more neutral question. I think , with "Do you ever" , the "ever" seems to make that rhetorical.